# How to capture URL that points to non-existent page/file?

Tags: php, linux, url

How to capture URL that points to non-existent page/file?

Lets say users enters a url like `www.myserver.com/randomString`, I would like to redirect the page to `index.php`, but also capture the "randomString"? I'm aware `.htaccess` can do the redirect on file not found, but what abotu the URL capture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Simple method:

Use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to find out previous address. It cannot be fully trusted since it can be manipulated by some agents.

#### More complicated method:

You may use router-like, let's say, index.php on `DocumentRoot` and hide it from URL. To elaborate, all the requests will pass from index.php. In your example, it will become `www.myserver.com/index.php/randomString` and with .htaccess you may hide index.php which will eventually become `www.myserver.com/randomString`.

Then you may capture whatever you want just analyzing `index.php`

Comment: Ok, I think that does what I'm hoping for. Basically any url entered after the domain name will be captured in order to generate a file with the same name

Comment: Could I do this on godaddy's shared account? $5/month

Answer (score 0):

If it is just for tracking you can use [Google Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/)

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I've updated my question.